# How to read a String Array from attrs.xml

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am implementing a custom view and want to define an array of strings in attrs.xml. Currently I am doing it as follows:

In attrs.xml file I have defined:

```
<attr name="twCells" format="string"/>
```

In activity_main.xml I am providing following data:

```
 app:twCells="A1,A7,G1,G7"
```

And finally in MyCustomView.java file I am reading twCell attribute as following:

```
private List<String> twCells = null;
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BoardView, 0, 0);
twCells = Arrays.asList(a.getString(R.styleable.BoardView_twCells).split(","));
```

My question: Is there any better way available to do this?

Answer (score -1):

If you agree to move your strings resources into the strings.xml file, you can do like this:

**in strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and to get a string:

```
String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];
```

Comment: While creating custom view, I have defined twCells under <declare-styleable> tag in attrs.xml, and while defining the layout of the screen in activity_main.xml I have provided the values of twCells.

Can you please explain a bit further in this context?

Comment: I am sorry unfortunately I am not able to solve your problem in this context since I have never used strings outside of the strings.xml file before.